# Find a conformal mapping $f$ that maps $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Re(z) > 0\}$ onto itself that maps $f(1)=2$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Find a conformal mapping $f$ that maps $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Re(z) > 0\}$ onto itself that maps $f(1)=2$.

So we need to ensure $f(1)=2$ and that the right half plane maps to the right half plane. Well, we can choose a Mobius mapping. Notice that the mapping

$$f(z) = \frac{z+1}{\frac{1}{2}z+\frac{1}{2}}$$

will satisfy $f(1) =2$ but it's not obvious to me that I can check that the right half plane maps onto the right half plane. In fact, my choice of $f$ above is only one of infinitely many choices that satisfy the constraint $a+b = 2(c+d)$. How can I choose a mapping in such a way that the right half plane maps onto itself?

Comment: What is $f(2)$ for your $f$?

Comment: $f(2) = \frac{2+1}{1+\frac{1}{2}} = 2$. Maybe you're hinting that my choice of $f$ is constant?

Comment: I am doing that, yes.

Comment: I'm not committed to that specific mapping of $f$, I'm more interested in the conceptual framework behind using $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ to find the $a,b,c,d$ so that the right half plane maps to the right half plane.

Comment: Multiplying by $i$  takes the right half plane to the upper. Next,  the upper half plane is fixed by any $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$   with real $a,b,c,d$  and $ad-bc > 0.$  Finally, dividing by $i$  takes us back to the right half plane.

Comment: @WillJagy That makes sense, but from there, how do you choose $a,b,c,d$ so that $f(1)=2$?

Comment: Any region which can be characterized in terms of the argument will be preserved by maps of the form $z\mapsto r.z$ where $r \in \mathbb R_{>0}$.

Comment: Grigor, the coefficients of Mobius transformations, as two by two matrices, multiply to give the correct matrix for the composition of the transformations. I guess you should carefully prove that yourself, especially work out the correct order when two coefficient matrices do not commute. Call the upper half plane matrix be $$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
a & b \\ 
c & d \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$   while  multiplying by some $w$ (either $\pm i$ )  is $$ \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
w & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: After you enforce your $f(1) = 2$ the outcome  is a collection of mappings parametrized by two real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct order of matrix multiplication   for this is
$$ \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
-i & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
a & b \\ 
c & d \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
i & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) =
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
a & -bi \\ 
ci & d \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Here we demand $a,b,c,d$ real and $ad-bc > 0.$   Your condition that $1$ map to $2$  by
$$  \frac{az-bi}{ciz +d}   $$
becomes $ a-bi = 2 (ci +d)$  **with real variables**, so that
$a-2d = (b+2c)i $  gives the restrictions..........

$$  \frac{2dz + 2ci}{ciz +d}   $$
from matrix
$$ \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2d & 2ci \\ 
ci & d \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$$  of determinant $2(c^2 + d^2)$

Comment: Very nice generalizable answer. For the last part, isn't  $a-2d=2(ci+b)$ impossible since $\mathrm{Im(LHS)}=0$ and $\mathrm{Im(RHS)} \neq 0$? (namely because $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$) Wait, maybe this means $b=c=0$? $\leftarrow$ which coincides with Arthur's answer/example

Comment: @GrigorHakobyan  My last phrase was the rearranged equation "so that 
$a-2d = (b+2c)i $  gives the restrictions"  This is possible when both sides are zero

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of Mobius transformations that do this, but perhaps the simplest one is $f(z)=2z=\frac{2z+0}{0z+1}$.